# How to add an Item to the specific index in the layout

Tags: qt

I am following this example to create a Flow layout:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-layouts-flowlayout-example.html

This doesn't have `addToIndex(int _index)` function, so I would like to implement this. Since this layout uses QLayoutItems, I would like to create a function which can insert an Item after the specific index.

How can I get the index of an Item as integer and insert to the layout?

UPDATE:

flowlayout.cpp

```
FlowLayout *flowLayout = new FlowLayout;
void FlowLayout::insertItem(int index, QLayoutItem *item) 
{
   if(itemList.size() < index)
   {
     itemList.append(item);
   }
   else
   {
     itemList.insert(index,item);
     QRect tmp = this->geometry();
   }
   update();
}
```

flowwindow.cpp

```
void FlowWindow::addLineBreak()
{

  flowbreak = new FlowLayoutButton(NULL);

  QLayoutItem *item = new QWidgetItem(flowbreak);
  flowlayout->insertItem(index, item);
  //flowlayout->addWidget(flowbreak);

}
```

flowlayoutbutton.cpp constructor

```
 FlowLayoutButton::FlowLayoutButton(QWidget *_parent):QWidget(_parent)
 {
  QBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;


  flowbreak = new QPushButton(tr("-------Label-------"));
  flowbreak->setGeometry(0, 0, 200,20);
  layout->addWidget(flowBreak);

  setLayout(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the following method:

flowlayout.h:

```
class FlowLayout : public QLayout
{
public:
   void insertWidget(int index, QWidget *w);
   // rest of the class from the example
};
```

flowlayout.cpp:

```
// new method
void FlowLayout::insertWidget(int index, QWidget *w) {
   addWidget(w);
   itemList.move(indexOf(w), index);
}
```

now you can use it by just calling (assuming you have a pointer to the layout named `flowLayout`):

```
flowLayout->insertWidget(2,new QPushButton("Button"));
```

Comment: Thanks :). But how could you also tell me how I can convert my widget into `QLayoutItem`?

Comment: assuming you have a widget, for example `QLineEdit *widget = new QLineEdit();` simply use `QLayoutItem *item = new QWidgetItem(widget);`

Comment: Yes, this solved compiler error, but now, it does not update the layout with the new item. Does this require another function lie `insertWidget()` ?

Comment: I have not tested the example, the addItem method does noting else but adding the item to the list. you can try to call `update();` at the end of the insertItem method. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it creates an empty widget in the given index

Comment: ok, what is the type of `flowbreak`? QWidget I guesss? in `addLineBreak()` what is the value of index? why do you call `QRect tmp = this->geometry();` in insertItem()? you never use tmp.

Comment: ok, now I have tested my insert method in this example. It works perfectly. Just add the following 2 lines in the windows.cpp file (after the addWidget calls): `QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Inserted");` and `flowLayout->insertItem(2,new QWidgetItem(btn));`

Comment: Thanks. I will try tomorrow morning and tell you the output :). Thank you very much for your help

Comment: hi, I tried and now getting this error: `error: no suitable conversion function from "QWidgetItem" to "QLayoutItem *" exists`. Could you edit the question?

Comment: did you forget the `new` keyword? `QWidgetItem(btn)` instead of `new QWidgetItem(btn)`?

Comment: Why is insert function used in `Window::Window()`? I am trying to call this from a button I used in FlowWindow.cpp `void  FlowWindow::addLineBreak()`. Is this possible?

Comment: actually there is a simpler way for all of that, I update my answer

Comment: Thanks :). I will save this as well. I will update my code after implementing all requirements.