# Wizard-like user interface with buttons next and back

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm developing an application using the Qt Designer and PyQt4, I need to make several screens where each screen I capture user-specific data, for that I need to implement a next button and a back button similar to

[image: https://files.support.epson.com/htmldocs/pho825/pho825f1/images/2knhw1.gif]

where the current screen closes and the following opens when the user clicks next or if he clicks back, the screen closes and opens the previous screen, I made an example with only the next buttons and back to exemplify, if I was not clear:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

class Frm(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Frm, self).__init__(parent)

        next = QPushButton('Next >', self)
        back = QPushButton('< Back', self)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()

        hbox.addWidget(back)
        hbox.addWidget(next)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    root = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = Frm(None)
    app.show()
    root.exec_()
```

In short: How do I implement a function that calls another screen and close the current at the click of a button?

Comment: Looks you want to use `QWizard`, there's a nice simple example [here](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/dialogs/trivialwizard.py)

Comment: You could hide and show certain widgets using the `setVisible` method.

Answer (score 5):

First about a misconception: you do usually not create/show one screen (window) and close another, you usually only exchange the content of a wizard-like dialog window upon actions like pressing the buttons. The window is alive the whole time until the multiple page task is finished.

So I take it your question is really about:

**How to exchange a widget in a layout?**

Since you may still use PyQt4 which does not yet have `QLayout.replaceWidget`, it's best to just use methods `removeWidget` and `addWidget` of `QLayout` and since `addWidget` adds a widget to the end of the layout items list, I prefer a dedicated layout just for the interchangeable content of your wizard (see also: [How to add an Item to the specific index in the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785729/how-to-add-an-item-to-the-specific-index-in-the-layout)).

Example code using PyQt5 but easily transferrable to PyQt4. Only the next button is implemented.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWizard(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # vertical layout, wraps content layout and buttons layout
        vertical_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(vertical_layout)

        # content widget and layout
        self.content_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout() # could be almost any layout actually
        self.content = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page1') # customize with your content
        self.content_layout.addWidget(self.content)
        vertical_layout.addLayout(self.content_layout)

        # back, forward buttons wraped in horizontal layout
        button_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addStretch()
        back_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Back')
        back_button.clicked.connect(self.back_button_clicked)
        button_layout.addWidget(back_button)
        forward_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Forward')
        forward_button.clicked.connect(self.forward_button_clicked)
        button_layout.addWidget(forward_button)
        vertical_layout.addLayout(button_layout)

    def back_button_clicked(self):
        """
        The back button is clicked.
        """
        pass

    def forward_button_clicked(self):
        """
        The forward button is clicked.
        """

        # remove old content
        self.content_layout.removeWidget(self.content)
        self.content.deleteLater()

        # create new content
        self.content = QtWidgets.QLabel('Another Page')

        # add new content
        self.content_layout.addWidget(self.content)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

wizard = MyWizard()
wizard.setWindowTitle('MyWizard Example')
wizard.setFixedSize(600, 400)
wizard.show()

app.exec_()
```

And it looks like:

[image]

However, as already written in the comment by [Marius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402710/gui-with-buttons-next-and-back-using-pyqt4#comment54596939_33402710), there is quite extensive support for such dialogs in Qt using [QWizard](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwizard.html#details). So I strongly recommend to use that instead. The example above is only to demonstrate the ability of inserting and removing widgets in layouts.

You should definitely use **QWizard** for such problems!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [`QWizard`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwizard.html) class that allows you to create wizards in Qt and PyQt. It implements all the functionality you want, and lots more. All you do is design your pages by extending [`QWizardPage`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwizardpage.html), and add them to the wizard. This is much simpler than doing the whole thing from scratch as you propose.

Answer (score 0):

> Old question but missing example with existing API

You don't need to create all structure of an Wizard by yourself. Qt (and PyQt) already provides a class called `QWizard`.

Basic example:

```
wizard = QtWidgets.QWizard()
page1 = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
page1.setTitle('Page 1 is best!')
page1.setSubTitle('1111111111')
lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
hLayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(page1)
hLayout1.addWidget(lineEdit)
wizard.addPage(page1)
```

Complete example and some explanation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTJ1QULxXjg

https://impatientprogrammer.net/2018/07/06/pyside-pyqt-qwizard-in-3-minutes/